# How to edit variables in another game object.(Unity C#)

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

Do keep in mind that I am not good at Unity.

I have a Game Object with a variable called hp. I have another Game Object with a trigger collider. When the trigger runs, I want it to edit the variable hp but I don't know how to edit variables from another game object.

Please may I have some help.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal and verifiable example of your code? Otherwise we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, the `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` function is called when a collision is triggered.

In argument of the function, you get a collider named `other`, which is a reference to the collider script your object collided with. As any script in unity, you can call `other.gameObject` to retrieve the colliding gameObject. From then, you can use the `GetComponent` function to find a script on the object.

In your case, lets say you have an object on which you put this script:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float hp;
}
```

You need to create another script that handles the collision. Put this on the object that collides with your player

```
public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float damages;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {  
        if(!other.gameObject.HasComponent<Player>())
            return;

        var player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
        player.hp -= damages;
    }
}
```